# unit testing - How can I pass string with comma to a testcase in DUnitX

Tags: unit-testing, delphi, dunitx

If I have a unit test with **string** parameter, and I want to check if the input string has a **comma** (`,`) somewhere, I should create an input string with a comma in it.

But how to pass it to the TestCase?

```
[Test]    
[TestCase('TestA', '12,34')]  //AValue1 gets only '12' instead of '12,34'
[TestCase('TestB', '12,,34')] //AValue1 gets only '12' instead of '12,34'
[TestCase('TestC', '12/,34')] //AValue1 gets only '12/' instead of '12,34'
[TestCase('TestD', '12\,34')] //AValue1 gets only '12\' instead of '12,34'
procedure ValueShouldHaveComma(const AValue1: string);
```

Comment: Please try double quotes `"`. E.g. `'"12,34"'`.

Comment: It gets then `"12`

Answer (score 7):

I have found it:

```
    [Test]
    [TestCase('TestA', '12,34', ';')] //AValue1 gets '12,34'
    procedure ValueShouldHaveComma(const AValue1: string);
```

The last optional parameter of the TestCase is the separator.

Comment: Wouldn't a char like  be better than ";"?

Comment: @Victoria: Personally, I strongly prefer ⌬.