# pass a list of floating point numbers to a DUNIT testcase

Tags: delphi

I need  to pass a set of floating point values to a Delphi DUNITX testcase .
The  solution with adding the separator char does not work for me.

Test_Int has the complete string and I can extract the  stored integer values,
the  separator char as optional  param does not have  any function acc. to  my  trials.

This  is  opposite to solution from [send 1 floating  point number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44538544/unit-testing-how-can-i-pass-string-with-comma-to-a-testcase-in-dunitx)
and  therefore  I fail with  transferring the  string with multiple real values.

```
    [Test]
    [TestCase('Test_Int', '1,2,3,4,5,6', ';')]
    procedure Test_Integer(const AValue1: String);


    [Test]
    [TestCase('Test_Floata', '1.5;2.4;3.4;5.6;7.0;8.0', ';')]
    [TestCase('Test_Floatb', '1,5;2,4;3,4;5,6;7,0;8,0', ';')]
    procedure Test_Floating(const AValue1: String);



procedure Test.Test_Floating(const AValue1: String);
begin
       xxxx:=AVlaue   // only get first  number :-( 
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

The separator is there to separate parameters for the test method. As you have only one string parameter in *Test_Floating*, there should no separator appear in the value list.

```
[Test]
[TestCase('Test_Floata', '1.5;2.4;3.4;5.6;7.0;8.0', '|')]
[TestCase('Test_Floatb', '1,5;2,4;3,4;5,6;7,0;8,0', '|')]
procedure Test_Floating(const AValue1: String);
```